# Java -How to implement code into GUI made in Netbeans gui builder?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, swingworker

I made a GUI using NetBeans GUI builder and it looks great! However, I've got no idea how to go about implementing code to change values inside of the GUI.

My program connects to a database and pulls information such as sex, room number, bed number, name and referral source for each individual patient. The purpose of the GUI is to represent any changes to that information every so often, so I want it to automatically sync with the database every 60 seconds or so. I can write the code for the database sync and I've already made the GUI.

[image] 
My question is how do I update the information displayed in the GUI made in NetBeans?

```
public class ConnectMSSQLServer {

static int bedCount;

public static int getBedCount(){


    return bedCount;

}

public void setBedCount(int number){
    bedCount = number;

}
public void dbConnect(String db_connect_string, String db_userid, String db_password) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);
        System.out.println("connected");
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        String queryString = "select f2 from beds.dbo.Sheet1$";
        String queryString1 = "select f3 from beds.dbo.Sheet1$";
        String queryString2 = "select f4 from beds.dbo.Sheet1$";
        String queryString3 = "select f5 from beds.dbo.Sheet1$";
        String queryString4 = "select f6 from beds.dbo.Sheet1$";
        String queryString5 = "select f7 from beds.dbo.Sheet1$";
        String queryString6 = "select f8 from beds.dbo.Sheet1$";
        String queryString7 = "select f9 from beds.dbo.Sheet1$";
        String queryString8 = "select f10 from beds.dbo.Sheet1$";
        String queryString9 = "select f11 from beds.dbo.Sheet1$";
        String queryString10 = "select f12 from beds.dbo.Sheet1$";

        List<String> locationList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> patientList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> refferallList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> DateList = new ArrayList<String>();
        // List<String> locationList = new ArrayList<String>();
        // List<String> locationList = new ArrayList<String>();
        // List<String> locationList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);

        while (rs.next()) {

            locationList.add(rs.getString(1));
            locationList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));

        }
        ResultSet rs1 = statement.executeQuery(queryString1);

        while (rs1.next()) {

            patientList.add(rs1.getString(1));
            patientList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));

        }

        Set<String> uniqueLocationList = new HashSet<String>(locationList);
        System.out.println(uniqueLocationList);
        setBedCount(uniqueLocationList.size());
        Set<String> uniquePatientList = new HashSet<String>(patientList);
        System.out.println(uniquePatientList);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConnectMSSQLServer connServer = new ConnectMSSQLServer();
    connServer.dbConnect("jdbc:sqlserver://******", "***", "********");
}
```

}

So basically I want to write code within the provided example that appends the data inside the GUI. Like bed1A.setIcon(emptyIcon); something like that, but I don't know how to change the values of the GUI from code that exists outside of it.

Comment: Your question seems a bit broad. Can you get more specific -- what specifically do you want to change? What GUI components are involved? Can you show pertinent code?

Comment: Show relevant code, then only we can help. No magic power lord bestowed upon me to see the code in the image and help you out.

Comment: I kind of meant for my quesiton to be broad, because I'm looking to change almost everything shown in the GUI. I just don't know how to implement the code generated by netbeans, its over 6000 lines and I don't know if I should just make a new class that extends this GUI class and then change the parameters somehow or edit the code within the GUI class.  An example would be that if the database value for room 1 changes to empty then I want to remove Christine from the room and change that bed color back to grey.

Comment: `"I kind of meant for my quesiton to be broad..."` -- If you want a broad answer, then it is to use MVC, Model-View-Controller, to separate out your program logic from the view, and to have model listeners change the state of the view. Another broad recommendation is to be sure to learn the GUI library well before using a code-generating utility, in other words, be sure that you know how to well code Swing by hand before using NetBeans to generate code, else you'll get stuck. If you want more specific rec's, then you'll still want to ask a more specific question I think.

Comment: @WeareBorg I'm not sure what code I could show you to help clarify this. I just want to know what I'm supposed to do with the GUI that was made with netbeans gui builder. I don't know how to use it with my own code. I can past some of the generated code from netbeans, but its over 6000 lines.

Comment: Ok, Seems like a good time to explain difference between front-end and back-end, I wont go in MVC like Hovercraft did, as I will get late to go home. So basically,  any UI is generally changed when some action happens. So, for example, a user clicks on some button, and then some code runs in backend, like reserves a place to stay in OceanBreeze and then gets an email. What you are asking us to do is, to look at the picture you posted, and ask us what to do in backend. It doesnt make any sense anyways. How to know whats going on in code by looking at image. Just answer that and anyone wil help.

Comment: I added an example database connection code that I will be using to some extent. Basically I want to use the code from this to change the values inside of the gui.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I guess I worded my question poorly, I'm sorry. Just didn't really know how to ask for what I need. I want to be able to edit the stuff inside of my GUI from another (main) class. And update the window as the database gets new data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Keep a Controller class, the application, the boss.
- Keep a DataModel class, field of the controller, for all the data, loaded from the database used to create the GUI; done by the controller.
- And then there is the View, your JFrame, a field of the controller.

Now in the GUI builder you want not to repeat yourself (DRY principly). All those room components should be a `List` of rooms. After using the GUI builder for adding some element, you can adapt the code for arrays/lists.

The controller can set things in the JFrame: you add to the JFrame: `addPatient(int room, int bed, String name)` and can fetch the component from a list and use `Ctrl-Space` to elect from `setText("Jane")` to whatever.

Make data classes like `Room`, `Bed`, `Patient`.

(Use version control.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, but how do I use the gui builder class inside my controller?. I tried extending it and implementing it but nothing seems to bring up the gui when I call new gui(); in my main method.

Comment: Switching from Design view to Source view you can expand generated code parts, see the fields declared: jPanel1, jTextField4 etc. Experiment in a separate project to do things like `jTextField.setBackground(Color.RED)` etcetera.